# Can I approximate$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/4} e ^{\tan(x)} \mathrm{d}x$ using Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question regarding the following integral, I know that its solution is Complex.

But my question is, can I approximate the integral to a real value, using Taylor series?
My analysis is the following.

$$I=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/4} e ^{\tan(x)} \mathrm{d}x=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/4} {\tan}^{i} (x) \mathrm{d}x$$
That is, approximate said series up to a certain $ i $, for example $ i=10 $.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} i e^{-i} \left(e^{2 i} (\text{Ei}(-i)-\text{Ei}(1-i))-\text{Ei}(i)+\text{Ei}(1+i)\right)$  ```Integrate[Exp@*Tan@x, {x, 0, Pi/4}]```   approximately, $1.27072$

Comment: Yes you can,  by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: The solution could be simplified with [these functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7BChi%28x%29%2CShi%28x%29%2CCi%28x%29%2CSi%28x%29%7D)

Answer (score 1):

From tables of integrals, using the digamma function
$$a_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 4}\tan^n(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{4} \left(\psi \left(\frac{n+3}{4}\right)-\psi  \left(\frac{n+1}{4}\right)\right)$$ Using $b_n=\frac{a_n}{n!}$
$$\frac { b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ So, no problem with convergence.

If you compute the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p b_i$$ you will see that
$$S_p=\alpha_p+\beta_p \,\pi+\gamma_p\,\log(2)$$ the coeffcients $(\alpha_p,\beta_p ,\gamma_p)$ being rational numbers.

For example
$$S_{10}=\frac{2536431377}{4572288000}+\frac{1960649 
   }{14515200}\pi+\frac{305353 }{725760}\log (2)$$ shows an absulte error of $1.22\times 10^{-9}$ which is more than sufficient.